# How Map and Reduce operations are actually carried out

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have gone through this question., can anyone give the correct answer with explanation?

Which best describes how TextInputFormat processes input files and line breaks?

A. Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses file splits is read by the RecordReader
of the split that contains the beginning of the broken line.

B. Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses file splits is read by the
RecordReaders of both splits containing the broken line.

C. The input file is split exactly at the line breaks, so each RecordReader will read a series of
complete lines.

D. Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses file splits is ignored.

E. Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses file splits is read by the RecordReader
of the split that contains the end of the broken line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this part of an assignment? What is your best guess so far? Based on what research? Were you able to rule out one of the answers already?

Comment: I am thinking the answer is E, but not sure, confused with answer A & E.

Answer (score 0):

Linerecordreader reads value for a map call until it encounters a new line(or a different delimiter if specified) with the help of below call for textinputformat type. So obviously a record will never end until it encounters a new line.

```
newSize = in.readLine(value, maxLineLength, Math.max((int)Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, end-pos),maxLineLength));
```

So Option A hold good.

Input file splits may cross line breaks. A line that crosses file splits is read by the RecordReader of the split that contains the beginning of the broken line.